# how to solve field and property is not initialized inc#.net when retriving sharepoint list data

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, bots

i got exception Microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldorproperty not initialized  while creating client context variable when fetching sharepoint list data in c#.net project,it throws server library version,server version,serverschema version error
            const string siteurl = "https://indica.sharepoint.com/sites/DemoBot/Lists";
            string login = "tghi@indica.onmicrosoft.com";
            string password = "

```
        try
        {
            foreach (var c in password)
            {
                securepassword.AppendChar(c);

            }
        var credential = new sp.SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securepassword);
        sp.ClientContext clientcontext = new sp.ClientContext(siteurl);
      clientcontext.Credentials = credential;
            sp.List olist = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
            sp.CamlQuery calmquery = new sp.CamlQuery();
            var username = "Test1";
            calmquery.ViewXml = $"<View><Query><Where>" + $"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/>< Value Type 
             = 'Text' >{username}</ Value > </ Eq > " + $"</Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit> 
          </View>";
            sp.ListItemCollection collistItem = olist.GetItems(calmquery);
            clientcontext.Load(collistItem);
            clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
```

Comment: can you share code snippet such that the error can be re-produced by the community.
and perhaps the line of code that throws error for more clarity

Comment: call the Load method on collistItem and olist and then executequery

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Server Libarary version, serverschema version and server version  shows exception that Microsoft.sharepoint.client.propertyorfieldnotinitialized

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
clientcontext.ExecuteQueryAsync(SuccessCallback, FailedCallback);
```

Then in SuccessCallback method, do whatever you wanna do next. This will make item retrieval asynchronous and success callback will be called once, items are retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to SharePoint Online, please use Microsoft.SharePointPointOnline.CSOM from Nuget Package:

[image]

After installing the library, the code snippet below to connect SharePoint Online should be working:

```
    string password = "********";
    string account = "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
    var secret = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        secret.AppendChar(c);
    }
    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/"))
    {

        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

[image]